# How to call a method of another class in one class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I want to call `MyView.circle()` method when I click on menu *Circle* but when I'm clicking on menu it is throwing a `NullPointerException`, which means that the object is not initialized as I expected.

Here is my code. Where am I going wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));
}


@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    menu.add(0,1,1,"Circle");
    menu.add(0,1,2,"Rect");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case 1:
            MyView.circle();
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public static class MyView extends View {
    private Context context;
    static Canvas can=null;
    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mPaint=new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        //circle(canvas);
    }
    public static void circle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       can.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, mPaint);
    }

    }           
}
```

Comment: Go through your code again properly! It is a mistake that is quite clearly visible. And it has nothing to do with what all you have written.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void static circle(c) {
```

needs to be changed to

```
public void static circle(Canvas c) {
```

Might I recommend spending some time learning Java before writing Android apps?